Changing scene baked lightmap according to the time of day
I need a dynamic light view in a mobile game without losing any performance. So I thought to resort to baking the light, but I'll lose the light dynamic feature.
And now I have a time system that controls the time of the game and the rotation of the sun and will control the intensity of its light and the temperature of its light.
So I thought to make a tool that bakes light throughout the day using the time system and according to the refresh rate (15 minutes, 30 minutes, 60 minutes), and the tool creates a scriptable object with a ready-made LightmapData  file according to the required time and a function to get the LightmapData file according to the wanted time .
So my question is: how much do the (lightmap change function) of the processor and RAM consume for the mobile? And is there a better way to implement the same idea?
example for changing the lightmap data file:

Daylight lightmap


Night lightmap




Measuring how much processor and RAM resources your custom lightmap changing code consumes sounds like a job for the Unity profiler. What do you observe when you use it?

The command is called in Start, Update after the required time has passed. So when I use the Profiler (Deep Profiler is off), I never find it, even if I search for it by name, and the only way to see it is to begin a sample in the script around the command LightmapSettings.lightmaps = lightMaps[time].lightMap; and I notice the sample name at the first frame only, and in the case of the Deep Profiler, I notice the command by its name in the first frame only.

Consider adding a button to trigger it on demand for testing purposes. But also, if you don't see any spikes in the profiler that make it stand out, it sounds like you have your answer: it's not creating enough impact to notice.

I did that and noticed that when I pressed the button for the first time, it generated garbage of 5.4 kb from EventSystem.Update() [Invoke], and then in the next frame, the command was executed with garbage of 1.4 kb also for the same reason. And LightmapSettings.lightmaps = lightMaps[time].lightMap; took 0.02 ms, and then every time I pressed the button after that, it generated 1.9 kb, and then after 3 frames or less, it generated 1.1 kb or less, and the command was executed taking 0.01 ms.

It sounds like you've answered your question, then. Evaluating whether these numbers are sufficient for your needs is a task you'll need to do yourself. If you'd like help investigating whether this performance can be improved, we'd need to see the full code for your implementation.

But I can't pinpoint the reason behind the creation of the garbage; was it due to pressing the button or changing the lighting map?

"If you'd like help investigating whether this performance can be improved, we'd need to see the full code for your implementation." We cannot help you with code we cannot see.

"We cannot help you with code we cannot see. "  Unity is closed source.  The C# Garbage collection schedule at runtime is unknown. Debug or release?  Too many unanswerable questions, beyond the user source code.

Yes, I know that, but I want to try improving the code myself first because it gives me the opportunity to improve or learn new skills.
